# Spaces Before and After Slashes

Tags: code

For example, a space after `\hfill` does not add a space to an output.

```
LEFT\hfill{}RIGHT
LEFT\hfill RIGHT
```

If I put another space in front of `\hfill`, then will this space change the output adding an invisible space?

```
LEFT\hfill RIGHT
LEFT \hfill RIGHT
```

Similarly, when tabulating, do spaces change an output?

```
Row 1&1.23&4.56&7.89\\
Row 2 & 1.23 & 4.56 & 7.89 \\
```

Here I add the example. It seems spaces do not affect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}\hline
asdf & asdf \\
asdf & asdf \\\hline
0.12 & 0.34 \\
0.56&0.78\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is more interesting if you have more than one `\hfill` in a line. And then, yes, spaces between the text and the subsequent `\hfill` make a difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
LEFT\hfill MIDDLE\hfill RIGHT\\
LEFT \hfill MIDDLE\hfill RIGHT\\
LEFT\hfill MIDDLE \hfill RIGHT\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the position of `MIDDLE`, these spaces add to the distance.

As for your question on the ampersands: you do not provide an MWE. Yet if you put this in an ordinary `tabular` the spaces won't matter (but increase the readability). In other contexts they may matter.

Comment: In the specific case of LaTeX `tabular`, an `\ignorespaces` is inserted at the beginning of each table cell, and an `\unskip` is inserted at the end, so it _looks_ like spaces are ignored around `&`, but they are actually _removed_.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks! But this sounds a little bit like semantics to me. If even the creator(s) of TeX call this `\ignorespaces`, why can't one refer to this "removal" as "ignoring spaces". The result is that the space does not create a space, and thus IMHO it is absolutely viable to refer to this as the space is being ignored. IMHO this is a perfectly viable point of view. And I was careful to say "won't matter".

Comment: Not TeX, as the primitive `\halign` (and the like) don't ignore spaces; this is a LaTeX thing. But yes, the idea is that this is transparent to the user and it should behave as if spaces were ignored. But the space removal by `\ignorespaces` by `\unskip` are quite different. For instance, the table `\begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}c}a&{ }b{ }&c\end{tabular}` prints `a bc`, because the space in `\ignorespaces{ }` is hidden by the `{`, so it gets to the output, whereas the space in `{ }\unskip` is not protected because at the time the `\unskip` does its thing, the `}` is long gone.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So you agree with my answer?

Comment: I never said I did not (sorry if it looked like so :-), I was just explaining how the space-ignoring happens, for whom it might interest

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik (and the cat) -- Nobody seems to have mentioned that multiple consecutive spaces are (except when `\obeyspaces` is in force) compressed to single spaces, and a space will indicate the end of a control sequence, hence is ignored.  Not the whole story, but these considerations do contribute to the outcome.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! Yes, this is all true. My take was to attempt to answer the points in the question at *some* level. Of course, you can add much more information, and it would be great if there was (or is) some exhaustive discussion on all the space related topics, but the scope of the answer is much smaller than that.

Comment: the space will also make a difference if you only have one `\hfill` but the text either side is wider (or the line shorter) as the minimum space is then a word space not 0, this is in fact the most common failure people putting a word space+hfill between two 0.5\textwidth minipages and finding they do not come side by side.